# NullInjectorError: No provider for DecimalProvider

Tags: angular, angular-module

Getting this error: `NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(StudentModule)[DecimalProvider -> DecimalProvider -> DecimalProvider -> DecimalProvider]:`

[image]

I have imported the `DecimalPipe` to the module but still getting the same error.
thought it may be a cache error so I ran `npm cache clean --force` and reloaded the project and reran `npm install` and `npm start` but the same error still appearing.

below is the code of the StudentModule:

```
import { DatePipe,DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
  imports: [
    .
    .
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [DecimalPipe],
  exports:[]
```

why this error is still appeaing after importing the the `DecimalPipe` to the main module?

Comment: `Pipe`s are not services, you shouldn't declare them in the providers array, instead, I think you need to set it in the `declarations` array

Comment: @Andres2142 they are exported from commonModule, the correct way is to declare in the providers

Comment: so if `DecimalPipe` lives within your `CommonModule` and is exporting the pipe, then it should be enough to just import in the `imports` array of your other module, and delete the providers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a module specific for your pipe.
`DecimalPipeModule` for example that declare and export the `DecimalPipe`.
So that you can `import` this module anywhere you want without problem to use the `DecimalPipe`.